# Process.OutputDataReceived not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, process, stdout

I have a simple function in a WPF project. I have a Progressbar and I want when the external program runs a command the Progressbar will be updated. the weird thing is, it only updates when the external program finishes.

the external program edits all the pictures in a specific folder, when it finishes editing a picture it's writing a new line.

```
public string RunExternalExe(string filename, string arguments = null)
    {
        var process = new Process();

        process.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(arguments))
        {
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
        }

        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        var stdOutput = new StringBuilder();

        // Use AppendLine rather than Append since args.Data is one line of output, not including the newline character.
        process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) =>
        {
            bgwMain.ReportProgress(i+=2);
            //Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
            //stdOutput.AppendLine(args.Data);
        };

        try
        {
            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();

            process.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("OS error while executing " , e);
        }

        if (process.ExitCode == 0)
        {
            return stdOutput.ToString();
        }
        else
        {

            throw new Exception("finished with exit code = " + process.ExitCode);
        }
    }
```

Is there something wrong with my code?
Should I talk with the programmers of the external program? and ask them to do something with their code that will envoke my event?

thank you

Comment: You have to set `process.EnableRaisingEvents` to true

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev it didn't work :/

Comment: I suspect the issue is with the WaitForExit.   The app you are calling is closing the standard output so you c# app is just waiting.

Comment: @jdweng which command should I use instead?

Comment: WaitForExit is waiting for the application to terminate.  You want to read from application continuously while it is running so you do not need the WaitForExit.

Answer (score 1):

It's (probably) because you're blocking the main thread, if this was async it would have time to do your stuff.

WaitForExit isn't async, so if you're running this process in the main thread it's going to hold up everything until it's finished.

My suggestion would be to make the RunExternalExe method async

```
public async string RunExternalExe(string filename, string arguments = null)
```

and

```
await process.WaitForExitAsync();
```

If that's not possible then run the process in a separate thread and await that.